# base 64 encoding in android

Tags: java, android, encryption

i am trying to Base64 encode my AES encrypted password.
i have added the file in src folder. here is the code.

```
package code.finalwork;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FinalWorkActivity extends Activity {
    private String pref_file = "pref.xml";

    TextView pass;
    TextView pass_cnf;
    TextView err_msg;
    Button done;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        pass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        pass_cnf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pass_cnf);
        err_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_pass);
        done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_done);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(pref_file,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean val = pref.getBoolean("firstuse", true);
        if (val) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor mod = pref.edit();
            mod.putBoolean("firstuse", false);
            mod.commit();

        }
    }

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void onclick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_done:
            String usrpass = pass.getText().toString();
            String cnfrmpass = pass_cnf.getText().toString();
            if (usrpass.equals(cnfrmpass)) {
                byte[] password = Base64.decode(usrpass, 0);
                byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                        6 };
                for (int i = 0; i < usrpass.length(); i++) {
                    key[i] = password[i];
                }
                try {
                    String passtostore = encrypt(usrpass, key);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                err_msg.setText("Password added");
                err_msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                err_msg.setText("Password Must Match");
                err_msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public String encrypt(String toencrypt, byte key[]) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] encryptedbytes = cipher.doFinal(toencrypt.getBytes());
        String encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedbytes, 0);
        return encrypted;

    }
}
```

this code is working fine if we comment the encryption code. but with these lines i generate error that application is stopping unexpectedly.
[image: this is what log cat shows]

Comment: Base64 is **not** an encryption. You should never use it for the purpose of keeping something secret. Base64 is way to **encode** arbitrary data as a string and anybody can get the original content. It's the same as saving the password as clear text.

Comment: The title of the question is misleading. Base64 is correctly used to text-encode the AES encrypted password (cfr. `encrypt`)

Comment: yeah thanks.but can u figure out the problem.

Comment: did you try removing the `Base64.decode(userpass,0)` and replacing it by the `userpass.getBytes(...)`? Base64 encoding expects a string with lenght multiple of 4 and might be the cause of the arrayOutOfBounds (depending on the impl)

Comment: yes i used password.legth and it run.although i don't know at the moment that the output will be correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is used to encode binary data into a 64-character subset of ASCII-7, which is safe to transmit over text-based protocols (like SMTP or HTTP).

One potential issue here is that you are trying to Base64-decode the user input, which is just a plain string in this line of your code:

```
byte[] password=Base64.decode(usrpass, 0);
```

To convert the password in plain text (string) to byte[], use:

```
byte[] password =  userpass.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Actually, Base64.decode has a string version as well. [Android dev ref](http://bit.ly/Mzqz8t)

Comment: @MikaelOhlson yep, but that does not help in this case. Base64-decoding a plain text string will fail (unless border cases where the string size is multiple of 4 and the characters belong to the 64-char subset used by the standard base64, in which case, it will give you some garbage)

Comment: You're right. I misread your statement. My bad. Although Base64-decoding a plain text string should still not give an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, since the input is truncated, and the statemachine keeps track of if we end up in a bad state. Removed my minus one. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in your OnClickListener. In addition to what @maasg wrote, these lines look mighty suspicious.

```
byte[] key = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
for (int i = 0; i < usrpass.length(); i++) {
    key[i] = password[i];
}
```

Unless you are doing something that is not readily apparent from your code, if usrpass is longer than key you will go out of bounds.

Comment: i enterd just 3 character long password .but the problem remains.

Comment: @Kamran, okay, then my answer is incorrect as well, even though you really, really should check for the length of arrays you're operating on. Have you tried using password.length instead?

Comment: yes i used password.legth and it run.although i don't know at the moment that the output will be correct or not.